# What is the source of this fitwa: "Whoever kills one Rafezi (7 or 10 Shia), He'll go to the Jannah"

Tags: source-identification, shiism, fatwa, jannah

Fatwa:

> من قتل رافضيّاً واحداً(سبعة او عشرة شیعه) وجبت له الجنّة
>
> Whoever kills one Rafezi (7 or 10 Shi'a), He'll definitely go to the Jannah

I see this fatwa in the internet and there are a lot of pages, clips, or videos about it. But as far as I searched through different websites, I could not find any sources establishing the authenticity of this fatwa. Is there any Quranic or Hadith source from which this fatwa has been deduced or it's just a political propaganda?

Comment: this is fitwa of noah el ghazi (نوح القاضی).

Answer (score 1):

I searched somewhat, but unfortunately I couldn’t find its reference. Accidentally I myself have heard this Fatwa as well. But I don't know where its reference is. In my opinion, there must be a reason that you cannot find the references of such questions and it could be related to the shamefulness of these Fatwas(rulings).

Actually the tellers or narrators of these kind of fatawas don't like to make public this shamefulness fatwa(s) (ruling(s)), since it could be a negative advertisement for them and would show their rudeness to the people of the world.

Although they will spread it between their followers to reach their profits, but logically they prevent from spreading of this shamefulness ruling in medias.

On the other hand, note that: there should be such Fatwas which make them doing such attacks (suicide attacks often between Shias...), otherwise nobody will doing suicide attack without any goal ...

**Meanwhile, the comment of User5072 can be helpful as he said: this is fitwa of noah el ghazi (نوح القاضی). – user5072 Jul 14 '14 at 9:35**

*Note: I don't mean that this is 100% impossible for you to find its source.*

Comment: One can conclude from your concepts that maybe this fatwa will be only a gossip. How did you defend upon this conclude?

Comment: Remarkable opinion of you. As I said usually they strive not to spread it in formal sources ... due to its negative ... / But this issue can be proved (to some extent) by hearing in some sites ... And Likewise (As a logical reason) it can proved by noticing to their acts  (Suicide attacking against  Shias) ) who they strive to kill many Shias ... So, there should be such Fatwas which make them doing such attacks, otherwise nobody will doing suicide attack without any goal ... / Thanks for mentioning this important point. Well done mate.

Comment: Meanwhile, I appreciate you who reminded to edit my answer, and added more constructive info. / Jazak Allah Khaira

Comment: Great work buddy. I searched for 'noah al ghazi' but I couldn't find anything. I will search deeper and announce here if any succeed.

Comment: This is very nice of you. Hope to find it ... / Of course as I remarked, "usually they strive not to spread it in formal sources ... due to its negative ... / But this issue can be proved (to some extent) by hearing in some sites ... And Likewise (As a logical reason) it can proved by noticing to their acts (Suicide attacking against Shias) ) who they strive to kill many Shias ... So, there should be such Fatwas which make them doing such attacks, otherwise nobody will doing suicide attack without any goal ..." ____ Good luck.